# Mongoose-Bug in storing result in an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to store data from my two collections aictePendingEvent and pendingEvent to store inside a common array and then send the entire array as response to the json.This is my code for the same

```
exports.getPendingEvents = (req,res)=>{

let obj1 = [];

aictePendingEvent.find({userid:req.userId})
.then((obj)=>{
  //  console.log(obj[0])
 obj.forEach((elem)=>obj1.push(elem))
})
.catch((err)=>{
 return res.status(400).json({"error":"some error is there"})
})

pendingEvent.find({userid:req.userId})
.then((obj)=>{
 obj.forEach((elem)=>obj1.push(elem))
}) 
.catch((err)=>{
 return res.status(400).json({"error":"some error occured"})
})

console.log(obj1)
return res.status(200).json(obj1);

}
```

but everytime i am getting a blank array as reponse , i don't know why .

Answer (score 1):

That's because the query with the promise doesn't block the code, so you are returning your response before the result of the query.

You can either chain the queries so you return the response inside your `then` block, or use async/await in the query, as this:

```
exports.getPendingEvents = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let obj1 = [];
                    
    const obj = await aictePendingEvent.find({ userid: req.userId });
    obj.forEach((elem) => obj1.push(elem))

                    
    const obj2 = await pendingEvent.find({ userid: req.userId })
    obj2.forEach((elem) => obj1.push(elem));
                    
    console.log(obj1)
    return res.status(200).json(obj1);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(400).json({ "error": "some error occured" })
  }
}
```